# Dynamic branch name for git based gems

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, bundler, config

I am using bundler to deploy gems from an in house git repository into my rails app. I would like to have different branch names for different groups, however, this:

```
group :production, :release_candidate, :staging, :demo do
  gem "my_inhouse_gem", '0.0.1', git: 'git@github.com:my_gem.git', branch: 'master'
end

group :development, :develop do
   gem "my_inhouse_gem", '0.0.1', git: 'git@github.com:my_gem.git', branch: 'develop'
end
```

fails with

```
You cannot specify the same gem twice coming from different sources.
You specified that mygem (= 0.0.1) should come from      
git@github.com:my_gem.git (at develop) and
git@github.com:my_gem.git (at master)
```

While the following:

```
group :production, :release_candidate, :staging, :demo do
  my_gem = 'master'
end

group :development, :develop do
  my_gem = "develop"
end

gem "my_inhouse_gem", '0.0.1', git: 'git@github.com:my_gem.git', branch: my_gem
```

Simply uses whichever group is printed last.

After reading up on it and finding this article: http://yehudakatz.com/2010/05/09/the-how-and-why-of-bundler-groups/ ,I realize this is because bundler will still execute the contents of every group, and then simply install the ones that match.

How can I have a dynamic branch name based on environment config in my Gemfile?

Answer (score 2):

Bundler isn't designed to handle this situation the way that you'd like. It's intended to provide a consistent set of gems. Groups can control which gems are installed in what environments, but not to switch the version of a gem.

There may be a better way to accomplish what you want. If you need to develop against an experimental version of a gem, you're probably better off doing it in a branch of your project.

See also: https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/751#issuecomment-22113199

Comment: Is there no way to programmatically hook into Bundler::DSL and extract the current group name at run time?

Comment: No, that's not how Bundler works. It resolves the set of gems before any groups come into play.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I worked around the issue:

At the top of my Gemfile:

```
     rails = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'default'
```

And then:

```
if rails.match /develop/i or rails.match /ci/ or rails.match /test/ or rails.match /default/i
  # if you wish to test locally against your branch
  #in_house_version = 'your_branch'
  in_house_version = 'develop'
else
  in_house_version = 'master'
end
```